# Setting Jenkins build with different color than red in case of time-out

Tags: jenkins

Sometimes, some of our builds in Jenkins reaching timeout and getting failed. This is fine by me, but quite confusing since one cannot know with first glance that the job terminated by timeout.

Is there any way coloring such build with different color, instead of the ordinary red one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can customize the color of build status using "Modern Status" plugin

https://plugins.jenkins.io/modernstatus/

Comment: But can you config it's color in case of time-out?

Comment: other way is to install this plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin
and which  links with abort build status , hope this will be workaround for you, along with "Modern+Status+Plugin"